# Token based authentification of QGIS Server services

Tags: arcgis-server, qgis-server, authentication, token

In ArcGIS for Server a token for a service can be generated in order to restrict the consumption of such service to one single url (Such approach might be necessary due to some strange legal framework in Germany e.g.).

Question: Is there something equivalent available in QGIS Server?

Comment: From what I can see QGIS Server doesn't support authentication itself - however you could setup authentication & authorisation at the web server level.The Apache [WebAuth module](http://webauth.stanford.edu/) for example would allow you to implement token based security, but wouldn't be straightforward to setup.  

Depending on your requirements you may find it easier to go with GeoServer if security is important as this includes a [key authentication module](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.2/user/community/authkey/index.html).

Comment: Geoserver support is as kes mentions - QGIS Server is unlikely unless a QGIS developer takes this on.